# Java ProcessBuilder can't find file in PATH

Tags: java, curl

I try to run `curl`from my java application. Here is my code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl",
                    "-T",
                    "\"" + tmp_dir + "client-" + node_id + ".war\"",
                    "\"" + tomcat_url + "/deploy?path=/client" + node_id + "&update=true\"");
Process p = pb.start();
```

yet, it gives the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

`curl` is in my System PATH and user PATH, and when I run `curl` from `cmd` it works perfectly:

[image]

Also, when I give ProcessBuilder absolute path to `curl` executable, it works, but I don't want to do that since my code should work with `curl` whatver directory it's installed into

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the shell (or command processor) that locates a file among the directories defined in the PATH variable.

Simply starting a subprocess with a path to a command and a list of arguments does not go through the shell, unless you explicitly code it to do so.

If you can't offload the exact position of curl into some system property, you may have to interpret PATH and try all directories and then call with the full pathname.

```
public static Path findAbsolutePath( String curl ){
  String path = System.getenv( "PATH" );
  String[] dirs = path.split( ";" );
  for( String dir: dirs ){
    Path toCurl = Paths.get( dir, curl );
    File curlFile = new File( toCurl.toString() );
    if( curlFile.canExecute() ) return toCurl;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Or call the command processor.

Comment: so, you're saying I have to call `cmd.exe` and somehow as an argument give him my curl command?

Comment: It is one of the options, yes. PATH should be in the environment passed to cmd.

Comment: I honestly don't understand half of what you're saying, I'm kinda new to this. Could you give an example or something?

Comment: Added a method to find the full path.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer because i was not able to fix this problem with all the existing answer:

This is one of the answers for any beginner.(mostly combination of all the existing answer).

1. In the Windows machine make sure `curl` is installed. (follow the google to install)
2. Make sure you add the `curl` `bin` path to environment system variable
3. Restart the machine. (Important!. Because i spent lot of time because the `processBuilder` was using the `PATH` that was not having the CURL in it. Restarting fixed it) This is reason for the original error in the question.
4. You can use `System.getenv( "PATH" )` to verify on the code.

**Addon**:  If you are using `POST`, then make sure the post payload is escaped when running through WINDOWS. and NOT escaped when running through MAC. I really do not know the problem but it took lot time to debug.
Escape in the sense: `"` with `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

[ProcessBuilder#ProcessBuilder(String... command)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder-java.lang.String...-) javadoc:

> It is not checked whether command corresponds to a valid operating
>   system command.

So you need to build the absolute path to curl in the string you pass to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this: Add "cmd /c" in front if running on Windows:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("indows")) {
  // We need to add "cmd /c" on Windows so that applications on the path are found by ProcessBuilder
  command.addAll(List.of("cmd", "/c"));
}
command.addAll(parameters);
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
...
```

Where `parameters` contains the actual program and arguments you want to run.