# How to execute shell script on windows using JAVA

Tags: java, bash, shell

Im trying to execute shell script in JAVA on windows machine . below is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String abc;
        String abc1;

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash.exe C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\test.sh");
        proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println(proc.exitValue());

        InputStream st1 = proc.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader red1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(st1));
        while ((abc = red1.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Stdout1: " + abc);
            if (abc != null) {
                abc1 = abc;
            }
        }

    }
```

the shell script is simple below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"
```

however, the exit value of script execution is coming as 127 and not the zero
I followed the below posts as well but no success.
tried with git.exe as well , still error . please suggest

[Execute bash script in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660512/execute-bash-script-in-eclipse)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27054/bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: You'll get on tons better with `ProcessBuilder` It makes IO a lot easier: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "bash.exe",  "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\test.sh"}).inheritIO();pb.start();`

Comment: First, you should use ProcessBuilder as g00se advises above. Second, 127 indicates file-not-found, which is completely normal if you don't have a copy of bash.exe at all, or it's not in the search path of your Java application. Make sure you include enough information _in the question itself_ to rule those things out.

Comment: By the way, why do you spell Java using capital letters? It's not an acronym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure bash.exe is in `PATH` as Charles Duffy said. Having bash installed without that being the case, is, after all, not much use. *When* that's the case and your script is in the current directory, the following is equivalent to your code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] command = { "bash", "test.sh" };
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO();
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(p.exitValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not Windows-centric enough to verify this myself, but It does look like queeg might be correct that `ProcessBuilder` doesn't do a full PATH search on its own, but instead invokes a call that searches only a fairly short set of paths (the working directory, a few builtin-to-Windows locations, etc) without referring to the environment. See f/e [ProcessBuilder can't find file in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300172/java-processbuilder-cant-find-file-in-path)

Comment: Can't test it now. But I'd be very surprised if a) bash.exe cannot work independently of other Windows shell interpreters and b) `ProcessBuilder` will *fail* to find bash.exe if it *is* in `PATH`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Windows will be happy with "bash.exe" (and "bash" if PATHEXT contains ".EXE") assuming that bash.exe is on the Path (which is very likely with WSL, as WSL puts bash.exe in %WINDIR%\System32)

Comment: Digging into this further -- [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) [is called](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dbb2c4b6ac01d2a3367a2354213d3b4230dfbb96/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/ProcessImpl_md.c#L331), which _does_ use the PATH... sometimes. I'm not sure I understand it well enough to grok exactly what the relevant conditions are. OTOH, there are existing Q&A entries that state that `%WINDIR%\System32` is in the search path even when the PATH environment variable _isn't_ honored.

Comment: bash does not like a Windows format filename parameter - anything with drive letter or Windows file `\\` separator will give rise to error code 127, so the command must be proper formatted Linux path as in my answer, or a relative path "test.sh" as in this answer by g00se

Comment: *bash does not like a Windows format filename parameter* I've got to say that's pretty odd for an executable running on Windows. Yes, it *is* perhaps running in a subsytem, but Cygwin seems to handle path conversions

Comment: @g00se Agree, it all depends on the "bash" (not mentioned). If WSL, bash is standard GNU/Linux so does not like Windows pathnames unless you run the `wslpath` translator

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you read from that process stdin and stderr to ensure the OS does not block it.

Here is one solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74169414/4222206

And here another: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74583583/4222206

One more thing: Even if your Windows cmd allows to run `bash.exe` or `git.exe` directly (which means these binaries are found on the system PATH), this won't work in `Runtime.exec()`. The reason is that the algorithm that searches for executables via the PATH environment variable is performed by the shell (that is cmd.exe on Windows or bash in Linux). But unless you `Runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c git ...")` there is no cmd between your Java application and the target binary. Thus you have to specify the full path to the executable yourself.

Comment: Java on Windows will throw `IOException : Cannot run program "bash.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` if the executable isn't located in the search `Path`. However `bash unknownfile.sh` will report error code 127.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You should use `ProcessBuilder` to launch as it provides better control over I/O streams, and the `Runtime.exec` call you use is deprecated. However the outcome would be the same in your case.

The issue here is that bash on Windows is expecting a Linux style pathname, and you are passing in Windows OS pathname.

Your `Path` environment for `bash.exe` is correct because you don't get `IOException : Cannot run program "bash.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`.

Thus `bash.exe` has run, but it reports exit code 127 which means `Command not found, or PATH error`. To fix you need to form valid GNU/Linux pathname to the script. If you are using WSL the C drive is mapped as "/mnt/c" so you need to run the translated path:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{ "bash.exe", "/mnt/c/Users/abc/Downloads/test.sh" };

// Using "bash" above should also work if "bash.exe" is in the Path and PATHEXT contains ".EXE"
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
p.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
System.out.println(p.waitFor());
```

You could avoid the OS pathname translation by using a relative path to the script and run from it's directory:

```
File exe = new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\test.sh");
// Set up relative path for the script
String[] cmd = new String[]{"bash", exe.getName()};

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).redirectErrorStream(true);
// Run from the directory of the script:
pb.directory(exe.getParentFile());
Process p = pb.start();
p.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
System.out.println(p.waitFor());
```

Comment: Sorry - just saw what you did ;)

Comment: Historical note - DOS and later Windows would accept paths with forward-slashes '/' as the separator at the system / os call level, it was only COMMAND.COM and CMD.EXE that would insist on using backslashes. (I don't know if that's still true, I haven't used Windows in a long time)

Comment: @StephenP Yes Java on Windows and some other tools accept both types of slashes, however GNU/Linux `bash` treats a Windows slash as either an escape for next character (if using single slash), or part of the filename (if doubled), not as a directory separator.